# How do I vacate the room correctly with semaphores in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, locking, semaphore

Firstly I have a room for 4 student.Students come the room one by one and when they come room keeper makes some announce.For example when first student comes to room keeper says :
"Last 3 student for room."
In addition that students can not exit one by one.They must go out together.
In this point I get confused.I can not overcome it.Here is my code :

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    sem_wait(&rooms[roomNumber]); // it decreases the capacity of room.
    sem_getvalue(&rooms[roomNumber],&stuCountInRoom); //stuCountInRoom =4 (initial value)
    printf("Student %d began work in the %d.room.\n",stuNumber,(roomNumber+1));
     if(stuCountInRoom!=0)
          printf("  %d. Keeper said :'The last %d student.Let's get up !'\n",roomNumber+1,(stuCountInRoom));


    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    sleep(5);
    sem_post(&rooms[roomNumber]);
    printf("%d.student has left the %d.room\n",stuNumber,roomNumber+1);

// sem_init(&rooms[roomNumber],0,4);

/*
I want to see  output like that :

"n.student began work in the 1.room
    Keeper said :'The last 3 student.Let's get up !
x.student began work in the 1.room
     Keeper said :'The last 2 student.Let's get up !
y.student began work in the 1.room
     Keeper said :'The last 1 student.Let's get up !
z.student began work in the 1.room
n.student has left the 1.room   
x.student has left the 1.room
y.student has left the 1.room
z.student has left the 1.room

But sometimes I can not reach true value of stuCountInRoom.
For example I got output as like: 

"n.student began work in the 1.room
    Keeper said :'The last 2 student.Let's get up !
x.student began work in the 1.room
     Keeper said :'The last 1 student.Let's get up !
y.student began work in the 1.room
     Keeper said :'The last 1 student.Let's get up !
z.student began work in the 1.room
n.student has left the 1.room   
x.student has left the 1.room
y.student has left the 1.room
z.student has left the 1.room */
```

How can I solve these question  ? Thanks your advices.
Rememberly there is one room in question.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking, but why not use a barrier? Block until `n` threads are in the "room" (i.e. call the barrier fn), then release when capacity is reached and reset the barrier. A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: Your question has me confused.  Your statement of preferred action says 3 students entered, 3 students exited.  However, you stated that 4 students must enter.  Then why 4 students entered then 4 students exited, you say that is wrong.  Please clarify

Comment: @user3629249 sorry I accidentally deleted it.